# Hbase/OpenTSBD connection refused error

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

I am new to HBase and OpenTSBD.
I followed all of the steps in OpenTSDB Manual: http://opentsdb.net/getting-started.html

However, when I get to the final step, I get the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1146) ~[zookeeper-3.3.4.jar:3.3.3-1203054]
2012-10-22 09:52:45,715 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2012-10-22 09:52:45,716 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

Could you please tell me what is causing the issue? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indicates that it's having trouble connecting to ZooKeeper.  If you're running on a single-node setup, you probably haven't started HBase, or it's not running properly.  Check HBase's logs.